# when persisting an entity with auto generated PK in JPA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jpa-1.0

```
@Id

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

Column(name = "CNTNR_SHPMNT_NUM")

@XmlAttribute(name = "cntnrShpmntNum")

private Long cntnrShpmntNum;
```

I have a Table with name `CNTNR` and I made its primary key as generated with identity but its not working for me in `JPA`.Giving sql `error-503` which says trying to insert a auto generated column.and when I tried with `Column(name = "CNTNR_SHPMNT_NUM",insertable=false)` 
its working for me but its not passing the generated value Back.The entity object giving me `null` as returned even the row inserted in table.

Comment: Which database? What's the meaning of the error code -503?

Answer (score 0):

Add `private long id;` between `@GeneratedValue(...)` and `@Column(...)` since you probably don't want the column `CNTNR_SHPMNT_NUM` to be both a value and a PK.